# jQuery XML via AJAX: missing some nodes occasionally

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, flot

I have a flot graph that polls data via `ajax` from an XML document. I use mode: `time for x axis`. It works fine, except intermittently, some values from the `xml Document` gets dropped. Here is the code that fetches `xml` via `ajax`.

```
function graphUpdate() { 
    $.ajax( { 
        url: "EnergyDM.xml",
        type:"GET",
        dataType: "XML",
        success: onxmlReceived,
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
        { 
            alert(textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    // setTimeout(graphUpdate,10000);   
}   

function onxmlReceived(data) {

    var xmlData = null;

    //for Non IE Browsers
    if(window.DOMParser) {
        //xmlData = data;
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlData = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/xml");
    }

    // For IE
    else {
        xmlData = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlData.async = false;
        xmlData.loadXML(data);
    } 

    $(xmlData).find('energyDM').each(function(){
        Rec_Count = parseInt($(this).find('edNum').text());
        d1=[];
        for(var i = 0; i < Rec_Count; i++) {
            if(i < 10) { 
                d1.push([(parseInt($(this).find('et000'+i).text(),10))*1000,
                    parseFloat($(this).find('ed000'+i).text())]);
            } else if(i < 100) {
                d1.push([(parseInt($(this).find('et00'+i).text(),10))*1000,
                    parseFloat($(this).find('ed00'+i).text())]);
            } else {  
                d1.push([(parseInt($(this).find('et0'+i).text(),10))*1000,
                    parseFloat($(this).find('ed0'+i).text())]);
            }   
        }
        plotWithOptions();
    });

}
```

The XML file looks like this:

```
<energyDM>
  <edNum>305</edNum>
  <TMF>UTC </TMF>
  <pm339> 1.271</pm339><!-- pm339 max energy demand value -->
  <pm340>1325033716</pm340><!-- pm340 max energy demand occured time -->
  <ed0000> 0.282</ed0000>
  <et0000>1325545093</et0000>
  <ed0001> 0.283</ed0001>
  <et0001>1325544792</et0001>
  <ed0002> 0.284</ed0002>
  <et0002>1325544492</et0002>
  ...
  <ed0305> 0.284</ed0305>
  <et0305>1325544492</et0305>
</energyDM>
```

When the returned XML misses nodes, if I use Chrome to view the values, it shows something like:

```
  <ed0023> 0.283</ed0023>
  <et0023>1325538176</et0023>
  <ed0024> 0.281</ed0024>
  <et0024>1325537875</et0024>
  <ed0035> 0.281</ed0035>
  <et0035>1325534564</et0035>
  <ed0036> 0.280</ed0036>
  <et0036>1325534263</et0036>
```

And this does not always happen. If I keep refreshing the page, it may drop few nodes, then the whole thing comes up, etc. And it is not always the same nodes getting dropped either.

I'd appreciate any hints.

Comment: FYI you can simplify your node name code to `'et' + ('0000' + i).substr(-4)` and get rid of obnoxious `if`s

Comment: Also, shouldn't `data` already be an XML document? Why are you parsing it again?

Comment: Are the nodes dropped because of your parsing or in the raw XML?  If the latter, what is generating the xml document?

Comment: @liho1eye, Thanks for that tip. My background is EE, and am learning Web (JS, php, etc) for a project. The Data is XML, you are rite. Using xmlData = data; and the "parse." method seemed to get the data. I have switched back to xmlData = data;.

Comment: @Mark: The nodes were found to have dropped in the responseText itself. Not after parsing. The xml file is generated by a microprocessor board. I will try out some changes, test and will post back. Thanks a lot for answering.

Comment: @aVC is they are dropping in the XML, then we need to see that code.

Comment: @Mark, The issue seems to have been with the XML file generator. The way the stack was handling more than one http requestes, it was corrupting the XML files. Did some fix for that, and now things seem to be in control. Thanks again. :)

Comment: You have a problem with XML generating. Need to see sources to resolve this problem.

Comment: Another thought, and if you choose to inquire, I have a nice function that goes deep, but wouldn't it be easier to convert the xml on the server side in php, then send it as a json object? I know it would make your end script alot easier to funnel through and put less strain on your user who maybe using a really crappy browser/computer

Comment: Not to mention the fact that activex is slowly being phased out, and unless you user is on IE, he prolly wont have an activex lib anyway, and just last month, chrome and and firefox were out-doing ie users 5to1, so your site maybe quickly out-dated if you stick with asp and activex controllers

Comment: I don't know how but you should close this question as you found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @MArk, The problem was with the XML generation. The processor from microchip  which works out the XML file uses a stack which caused some bugs when multiple hits were made to the server simultaneously. When this happens, the subsequent interrupts were handled without completely taking care of the current action. This was found, and fixed and now the xml is good.